# Unity Dynamic Parameters/Arguments type in javascript

Tags: javascript, unity-game-engine

I whant get argunet with dynamic type.
I have head about Generics, but I don't find there information about javascript dynamic type.
I hope that here anybody can help me. Thanks.

```
    public function addItem (item) : boolean {
        if (!item || !item.weight) return;
        if (item.weight > item.weight + inventoryWeight) return false;
        items.push(item);
        inventoryWeight += item.weight;
        return true;
    }
```

I need convert this code in js

```
public class SomeClass 
{
    //Here is a generic method. Notice the generic
    //type 'T'. This 'T' will be replaced at runtime
    //with an actual type. 
    public T GenericMethod<T>(T param)
    {
        return param;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> but I don't find there information about javascript dynamic type

Javascript does not allow generics. You **can't** do this in Unity with Javascript. You can only use generics with C# and Boo which Unity supports. Please transition from Javascript to C# if you want to use generics.

[Here](https://unity3d.com/learn/tutorials/topics/scripting/generics) is Generics tutorial for C# and Boo. No sample code when you click on the Javascript tab. If you decide to transition to C#, click [here](https://unity3d.com/learn/tutorials/topics/scripting) for the official Unity tutorial for C#.

Comment: i have all project on js and i'm writing on js all time, and if i have problems whith dynamic args then i must write on c# ? And there is no decision?

Comment: Nope. When I mean transition to C#, I mean learn C# and start coding with C#. I provided a link for that here. It's not hard to learn. After learning it, port your scripts to C#. You can also mix C# and Javascript together but I wouldn't do that if were you as there are problems you will run into in the future.

Comment: oh, okay, thx man, you would know, I spent much time looking
I know C# little) becouse i written on C

Comment: You are welcome. You didn't find what you were looking because it doesn't exist. Don't forget to accept answer if you think your question has been answered.